# Finding Paths within a string

Tags: c#, string, file, path, directory

Given a large chunk of text, containing a few thousand absolute paths (dirs and files) mixed in with other random data, how can I efficiently extract them?

For example :

[randomtext]**c:\file.txt**(23, 56, 49)[randomtext]**c:\file2.txt**[34, 456]...

Annoyingly, it also contains paths within text like this :

blahblah{c:\file.txt}blahblah   (ignore the {})

So using pattern matching libraries like REGEX won't work

I'd like this to work on any string, without any knowledge of patterns that may be being used, as I can't assume the patterns will be the same in the future.

Currently I'm doing the following :-

Look for the ':' char, if it has a letter to the left and a letter to the right, then jump back one char and use this as our starting point. Now, iterate over the string from that point (until another ':' is encounted or you have jumped over MAX_PATH number of characters), creating a substring at each iteration and using System.IO.File/Directory.Exists() to see if its a valid path. If it is, then pull out the substring as a valid path...

...repeat the same process for the remaining string.

This works, but is very slow as you do hundreds of thousands of System.IO.File/Directory.Exists() checks.

Comment: will you have only file paths? or directory paths aswell?

Comment: @eugecm - I've edited the description as to why not.

Comment: @Sudhakar - Unfortunately, both

Comment: Your _blah{...}blah_ example is very unclear (give a literal sample) and it doesn't seem to exclude regex.